# Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr

Running R 4.0.2 and dplyr 1.0.2

I am trying to use `n = n()` in a summarize call on a srvyr object:

```
relduration_by_age_grp <- l %>% 
  filter(ongoing == 0 & ptype == i) %>% 
  select(ego.id, ptype, age.grp, ego.age.grp, duration, ego.wawt) %>%
  mutate(min.age.grp = ifelse(age.grp < ego.age.grp, 
                              age.grp,
                              ego.age.grp)) %>%
  srvyr::as_survey(ids=1, weights=ego.wawt) %>%
  group_by(ptype, min.age.grp) %>%
  summarize(n = n(),
            wtd.median = srvyr::survey_median(duration, na.rm=TRUE),
            wtd.mean = srvyr::survey_mean(duration, na.rm=TRUE), 
            median = srvyr::unweighted(median(duration, na.rm=TRUE)),
            mean = srvyr::unweighted(mean(duration, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Based on other questions/answers, I've also tried using `dplyr::summarize(n = dplyr::n(),` but that results in the same error.  Is the problem that it is not possible to use dplyr n() on a srvyr object?  There does not appear to be a similar function in srvyr that can be used in a summarize call.

thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Can you also share your `sessionInfo()` so we can see what packages are loaded?

Comment: Hi Martina! Long time no see.

Comment: Hey Ben -- nice to see you too :)

Comment: I also found that sometimes loading plyr on top of dplyr can make n() or group_by not to work and yield that message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, unlike `dplyr` (which accepts pretty much any summary function that returns a scalar, as well as its own specialized functions such as `n()`), `srvyr::summarize` gives you a limited choice of functions: from `?srvyr::summarize`,

> Summarise for ‘tbl_svy’ objects accepts **several specialized
> functions**. [emphasis added]

i.e., `survey_mean`, `survey_total`, `survey_ratio`, and a couple of others

Here's a hack that seems to work: calculate the sum (`survey_total`) of the inverse weights.

```
library(srvyr)
data(api, package="survey")
aa <- (apistrat 
      %>% as_survey_design(strata=stype, weights=pw) 
      %>% group_by(stype) 
)
aa %>% summarize(n=survey_total(1/pw))
```

This matches `table(apistrat$stype)`

Comment: Thanks!  I figured the limitation was related to srvyr.  This works perfectly

Answer (score 24):

The cause of this error is R’s confusion with which summarize function (dplyr vs. plyr) it should use.

Fortunately, we can tell R explicitly the package that we want to use by specifying the name and :: in front of the function.

so use  `dplyr::summarise()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is because you loaded a package, such as "operators", that masks "%>%" from dplyr package.

Comment: That’s not it, and Ben’s answer already explains the real cause and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this - dplyr::summarise() to run the code for counting the number of data points in your database.